Timer delay fluctuations in Java - how to improve?
I am trying to put together a timer class for a game. Until now, I was just using javax.swing.Timer, but after trying to do some operations that require more exact timing (specifically visual interpolation between two ticks' states when rendering more frames than there are ticks), I found this class's limitations and it proved unusable.
I tried to put together my own timer, going off available functions and just how I intuitively imagined a timer could work like this. It seems to give better results, yet there are still weird fluctuations, some of which don't make sense with the code written (image with stats). Like, how could the delay ever be smaller than 5? The condition for the function firing is the delayed timestamp being reached. Could this be some weird race condition?
logged time delays, printed by the runFunc() function run threaded
This is the entire test class for this (just deleted package line).
public class TimerTest {
    // for debug
    public double averageTimeMillis;
    int timesLogged;
    // Timer vars
    long lastTickTimeMillis;
    long lastTickTimeNano;
    long nextTimestampNano;
    long delayNano;

    public TimerTest(long delayNano) {
        timesLogged = 0;
        averageTimeMillis = delayNano;

        lastTickTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        lastTickTimeNano = System.nanoTime();

        this.delayNano = delayNano;
        nextTimestampNano = lastTickTimeNano+delayNano;

        new Thread(this::run).start();
    }

    private void run() {
        for (;;) {update();}
    }

    private void update() {
        long timeNowNano = System.nanoTime();
        if (timeNowNano>nextTimestampNano) {
            // Run, or threaded*
            new Thread(this::runFunc).start();
//            runFunc();
            nextTimestampNano+=delayNano;
        }
    }

    private void runFunc() {
        long timeNowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeNowNano = System.nanoTime();

        long millisDelay = timeNowMillis - lastTickTimeMillis;
        long nanoDelay = timeNowNano - lastTickTimeNano;

        averageTimeMillis = (averageTimeMillis*timesLogged+millisDelay)/(timesLogged+1);
        timesLogged++;

        System.out.println(millisDelay + " | " + nanoDelay + " | " + averageTimeMillis);

        lastTickTimeMillis = timeNowMillis;
        lastTickTimeNano = timeNowNano;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimerTest(5000000); // 5 ms delay, just for testing, in game will be higher
        for (;;) {} // to let timer run
    }
}

Another weird observation is that after the "//Run, or threaded*" comment, running the function normally seems to give significantly lower fluctuations than running it threaded. The reason I threaded it is that I don't want the run of the function to slow down the timer, were it to run longer than the delay. But now that I think about how two instances of runFunc() changing the same state simultaneously would work, no threading might be the right approach. It does still however produce fluctuations commonly. fluctuations with runFunc() not on a new thread
Anyone with experience with this in Java have any tips on why the fluctuations might happen, and how to fix it?
I tried debugging, however the specifics of the task make that difficult, and I didn't get any good results.
I tried increasing the delay, which realistically it will be used with a delay of at least 10-20 ms, and it does seem to minify the fluctuations, but only because they don't seem to scale with the delay, so they have a smaller impact on bigger numbers. Their frequency doesn't seem to be impacted (from a glance).

The average clock has a resolution of +/- 15 ms. You are expecting many thousands of time more precision. You will not get it. It isn't available.

please consider the following question and its answer Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

Did you try the java.util.Timer? You can schedule a repeated task in either fixed-rate or fixed-delay

By its very nature Java is not very suitable for providing stable Real Time behavior at runtime. There is usually a Garbage Collector, there is often a JiT Compiler performing optimizations at runtime, etc. Some of that can be turned off, but don't expect any strong guarantees for performance.

You don't need for (;;) {} // to let timer run

Have you tried to use a Thread pool (prepopulated) or VirtualThreads instead of new Thread()?

Your timer has a few problems. You are correctly adjusting for delays in one way, namely: The next 'event' should trigger not 'X seconds after processing the last one' but at a set interval: If for whatever reason a timer fire is 'late', then the next timer fire should happen sooner to account for that. But where you've gone a bit wrong is that there's no catchup mechanism. What if a timer tick is very late? What if in general the system simply cannot proc ticks as fast as they fire? Your system will get hopelessly behind.

The more egregious problem here is that this timer of yours busy loops - it never freezes, so it occupies one core continuously, wasting millions of cycles executing System.nanoTime() over and over and over. Most of the CPU is busy with this instead of your actual game! A thread that never sleeps is a broken thread, simple as that.

Your timer firing events should be long enough that sleeping is feasible (so, milliseconds. But keep using nanoTime, System.cTM is very slow and can skew. Just, delayNano should be a few milliseconds at least! - you need a sleep, and you need a catchup mechanism. Best catchup mechanism updates the actual runFunc  to take a 'count' parameter. runFunc(5) means: Do the work of 5 ticks worth in a single go as efficiently as you can. We're playing catchup, instead of calling you 5 times I'm just calling you once.

for (;;) {update();} ← You are choking your CPU with this, effectively stealing CPU time from other threads.  javax.swing.Timer works pretty well;  perhaps you were doing something that was interfering with its ability to function properly?
